# parsing a list file (awk/bash)

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

What i'm going to do is creating a csv file out of a parsed list.

```
[input.txt]

This is a list of all gadgets.
Version: 11
Created by: jayFour

1  Toy    no    ordered  
2  Box    no    ordered  
3  Spade  yes   in_stock  
4  Nail   yes   in_stock  
5  Chair  no    ordered
6  Table  yes   in_stock
7  Apple  no    ordered
9  Phone  yes   in_stock

# generated 2014
```

Now i created a script, which should do an 'awk' and create me a csv file like this:

```
[output.csv]

| ID  |  Item  |  Status  |  Stock     |  
|  3  |  Spade |  yes     |  in_stock  |  
|  4  |  Nail  |  yes     |  in_stock  |
|  6  |  Table |  yes     |  in_stock  |
|  9  |  Phone |  yes     |  in_stock  |
```

"|" represents the table borders.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ifiles=`ls input.txt`

for ifile in $ifiles
do
  echo "ID;Item;Status;Stock\r" > output.csv
  id=`awk '/yes/' $ifiles | awk {'print $1'}`
  itm=`awk '/yes/' $ifiles | awk {'print $2'}`
  stat=`awk '/yes/' $ifiles | awk {'print $3'}`
  stck=`awk '/yes/' $ifiles | awk {'print $4'}`
  echo "$id;$itm;$stat;$stck\r" >> output.csv
done
```

As you can imagine, that did not work this way. I got issues with breaks within my csv (maybe caused by faulty read-in/parsing my input-file line by line.

Well - How to fix? :)

Comment: Where do you use the variable "ifile"? -- It is not used

Comment: The variable "ifiles" only contains 'input.txt'. What do you want for?

Comment: I shortened my script. i'm using "ifile" for generating output-filenames. not here, but doesn't matter, i guess.

Comment: Where are you putting the single quotes and the { in the awk code?

Comment: Your script assigns EVERY first field in EVERY line of the file "input.txt" to the variable id; EVERY second field to the variable "itm", and so on... Not just a line. Please try to run yourself the first line containing awk and watch its output.

Comment: sorry, don't get the issue with "EVERY first field"

Comment: awk '/yes/' $ifiles | awk '{print $1}' prints "3 4 6 9" (the first fields of all file lines containing a "yes" string.

Comment: You seem very confused about awk and shell, both in syntax and semantics. Get the books Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition, by Arnold Robbins and Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson.

Comment: Ur right, i'm actually not a coder, just have to tinker some things. But ur advice is helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this achieve what you wish:

`cat input.txt | awk 'BEGIN { print "ID;Item;Status;Stock" }; /yes/ { printf "%s;%s;%s;%s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4 }'`

To be placed inside your loop of course.

Explanation: start by printing the Header (BEGIN block) then for each line whith a yes, print each field separated by a ';'

There's more elegant way for this in awk, but they are less easy to understand at first.

i.e:  `cat input.txt | awk 'BEGIN { OFS=";"; print "ID","Item","Status","Stock" }; /yes/ { print $1,$2,$3,$4 }'`

Here I let awk manage the output by giving him the Output Field Separator (OFS) within the BEGIN block;

Output is:

```
ID;Item;Status;Stock
3;Spade;yes;in_stock
4;Nail;yes;in_stock
6;Table;yes;in_stock
9;Phone;yes;in_stock
```

Edit for completeness: you bash would become:

```
#!/bin/bash

ifiles=`ls input.txt`
echo "ID;Item;Status;Stock\r" > output.csv

for ifile in $ifiles
do      
  cat $ifile | awk 'BEGIN { OFS=";"}; /yes/ { print $1,$2,$3,$4 }' >> output.csv
done
```

As you may not want to repeat the header, it is done before the loop and not anymore in the awk part.

Comment: awk is perfectly capable of opening files, so UUOC. Any time you find yourself writing a shell loop just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach.

Comment: I don't have the prevention to teach anyone how he should do better. I'm trying to answer the question as close to possible as it could be a simplified part. I would be happy to extend but I've not the pretention to guess what is in the Op head as its how I understood SO guidelines: don't answer you should use something else. The OP could have other needs with the file name than just produce a delimited file bur did not exposed them here as its not he's problem... (sorry if I sound rude(this comment sounds rude to me),my English is getting poor lately)

Comment: No, you don't sound rude. Answering a question to help the OP is perfectly reasonable and commenting on the answer to a question to help the poster of the answer and the OP is also perfectly reasonable. In both cases, we're just trying to help. It's very often good to tell the OP to use something else as they often ask how to implement the only solution they can think of (e.g. "how do I escape special characters in sed?") when they should really ask how to solve a problem (e.g. "how do I replace string a with string b regardless of chars they contain?") so they can learn a better solution.

Comment: thank you guys. it works both ways. and i do understand ur comments regarging my faults, /me just needs some exercising. =)

Comment: No problem ;) As @EdMorton says, his way is more effecient, looping over a list of files is usually unnecessary as the cat and pipe, I just found it usually more understandable when starting with awk.

Answer (score 2):

Start with this:

```
awk -v OFS=';' '
BEGIN { print "ID","Item","Status","Stock" }
$3=="yes" { $1=$1; print }
' $ifiles
```

Let us know if anything needs to change. Note that I'm leaving $ifiles unquoted as you did under the assumption you need to do that and understand all the associated caveats.